# Moment.js - Can't calculate .diff between dates properly if they are in different days

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Can someone explain me why this isn't working properly. Below is a code that is using moment.js to calculate differance between CURRENT time and my variable times.

```
           //breakfast
           var breakfasttimeleft = moment(person.breakfast, 'HH:mm');
           console.log("Person breakfast is at:  " + person.breakfast + " -- Current time is at: " + currenttime);
           console.log(breakfasttimeleft.diff(now, 'minutes'));

           //lunch
           var lunchtimeleft = moment(person.lunch, 'HH:mm');
           console.log("Person lunch is at:  " + person.lunch + " -- Current time is at: " + currenttime);
           console.log(lunchtimeleft.diff(now, 'minutes'));

           //dinner
           var dinnertimeleft = moment(person.dinner, 'HH:mm');
           console.log("Person dinner is at:  " + person.dinner + " -- Current time is at: " +  currenttime);
           console.log(dinnertimeleft.diff(now, "minutes"));
        })
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT:

```
CONSOLE LOG
Person breakfast is at:  18:35 -- Current time is at: 18:35
0
Person lunch is at:  23:35 -- Current time is at: 18:35
300
Person dinner is at:  04:35 -- Current time is at: 18:35
-840
```

Dinner is totally messed up on some places, like on above and on others it works perfectly fine.
Basically.. it doesn't know how to look up hours if the other date is in another day, so instead it will look up differance between these 2 hours in current day.

18:35 to 04:35. It is suppose to be from 18:35 to 04:35 in the morning, which is around 10 hours. Instead what it does is calculates time from 04:35 in the morning to 18:35 later that day.
How can i fix this to work properly?

It appears I have to state a day aswell.. how can i format it so it is Day + Hours + Minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're simply providing it with times, but it has to store some date too. If you don't provide a date it simply gets initialized to the current date, which is exactly what's happening in your case.

Also there simply is no way for moment to know the date you want it to set. You'll have to set the date on your own.

Simplest thing would be to just [add a day](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) to the date you created: `dinnertimeleft.add(1, 'd')`

If you want to supply a date too(ideally a complete one) you can use this format string: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`
Or create your own one following [this](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) documentation.

Comment: Yeah i just figured that out. 
Do you know how i can format it?   Right now its HH:mm. 
How would i set day aswell?  Is it D:HH:mm ?

Comment: @TheGarrus updated my answer. If you always only need to add/subtract one day the first way is probably simpler.

Comment: I needed the second answer YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm 
thank you